# If cell contains then continue function

Tags: excel, vba

How can I implement if Sheet1 has row16 filled with anything it'll continue the function. If row16 is blank then skip function?

Initially I wanted row 2 to row15 from sheet1 to be copied into sheet2 and anything from row16 will be put on sheet3.

The code I have currently works fine with anything over 15 rows of data. But if it gets below 15 rows it gets buggy.

```
   With Sheets("sheet1")
      Set Rng = .Range("T2:T15")
   End With
   For i = 1 To Rng.Count * 2 Step 2
      r = r + 1
      Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i + 13).Value = Rng(r).Value
      Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & i + 14).Value = Rng(r).Value
Next i

   With Sheets("sheet1")
      Set Rng2 = .Range("T16", .Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
   End With
   For i2 = 1 To Rng2.Count * 2 Step 2
      r2 = r2 + 1
      Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & i2 + 7).Value = Rng2(r2).Value
      Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & i2 + 8).Value = Rng2(r2).Value
Next i2
```

Comment: I tried the code and it works fine, if that is what you require. Could you share some images of the desired results in `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` or describe in more detail what is wrong with the output?

Comment: Yes my code does work fine, however when sheet1 has data less than 16 rows, sheet3 will copy the information from sheet1. 

if row 16 is blank I would like it to ignore copying things from into sheet3.
as sheet2 will have information from Sheet1 T2-T15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CountBlank vs CountA

- Replace your second `With` block with the following one:

**CountBlank**

```
   With Sheets("sheet1")
      If Application.CountBlank(.Rows(16)) = .Columns.Count Then
          Exit Sub
      Else
          Set Rng2 = .Range("T16", .Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      End If
   End With
```

---

**CountA**

- In this case, `If Application.CountA(.Rows(16)) = 0 Then` is unreliable because it will 'pick up' any cells containing formulas evaluating to `""`. Although sometimes you might need this behavior.

---

- If you just want to check cell `T16` do the following:

**Len**

```
   With Sheets("sheet1")
      If Len(.Range("T16").Value) = 0 Then
          Exit Sub
      Else
          Set Rng2 = .Range("T16", .Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      End If
   End With
```